# Can I insert multiple People Search Core Result Web Parts on the same page?

Tags: web-part, people-search

I have created a department page displaying a gallery of staff along with a few select fields from their user profile.  I successfully used a People Search Core Results web part with a Fixed Keyword Query `(Department:"Engineering")` to generate this gallery on the page.

Some of the departments break down into several teams, so I added a new custom `Team` property onto the user profiles and I am now using multiple People Search Core Results with a slightly more precise Fixed Keyword `Query (Department:"Engineering" AND Team:"Management")` to call up individual teams with each web part.

The problem is that the result of the second web part is duplicating itself over the results of the first web part (which normally displays fine on it's own) so they are identical, so I would like to know if there is any problem with using multiple People Search Core Results web parts on a page?

Also, if I use the following query:

```
(Department:"Engineering" AND Team:"Management")
```

Will there be an overlap of results if I use the following query for another team on a different web part on the same page because they both contain the word "Management"?  I thought using the speech marks would require the query string to be an EXACT match.

```
(Department:"Engineering" AND Team:"Project Management")**
```

I'll be very grateful for any insight as to why this is happening!

Comment: The two mistakes I made that caused this problem were:

1. I needed to select different **Cross-Web Part query ID** for each People Search Core Results web part to prevent them interacting with each other.

Comment: 2. The syntax of my first query **Department:"Engineering" AND Team:"Management"** seems open for the results of my second query **Department:"Engineering" AND Team:"Project Management"** because they both contain the terms **Engineering** under Department and **Management** under Team.

I thought putting the term **Project Management** into quotes would force the query to accept only that exact string, but apparently it will still accept any of the keywords individually.  

I haven't figured out the correct syntax to resolve that particular issue, but at least I know what the problem is now.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem of inserting multiple web parts on a single page as in this solution all the web parts use the same ID, but do not interact with each other:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/707e89a0-4b28-403f-a0fd-ad400bd033d5/cross-web-part-query-id

I still didn't find out the correct syntax to force the query to only display results of the 'exact' query string used, but I shall keep looking...

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Hi Luccio.  

In terms of using multiple queries on the same page, I ultimately found that keeping the "Cross-Web Part query ID" set to "User Query" and applying my query to the "Append Text To Query" field on each web part enabled me to use as many as 12 different People Search Core Results web parts on the same page with no issues.  

In terms of the other issue of distinguishing between the departmental names (for example, "Management" and "Project Management") I didn't come up with a solution and instead I just renamed "Management" to "Central Management" and worked around the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, "Append Text To Query" is not available in SP2007 so it is not applicable in my case.